# Generate file at compile time in Rust/Cargo: Procedural macros or/and Build.rs?

Tags: rust, build, macros, rust-cargo, compile-time

I want to generate a file when I compile me project with a specific feature.
I've got some specific "String" in my code, I want to get them at compile time and write a file with all of those.

To define those String, I did a macro like this:

```rust
// Currently, this macro does nothing, it's just to extract the value in the future
string_id!("MyString");
```

So! I saw that I can do this with procedural macro, but I do not have any guarantee all files will be read. Plus, I would like to save results in a state, but not sure I can create a global state for procedural macros.

Build.rs can be used to do operation at compilation as-well, but I'm not sure I can read/get all those string values, maybe by parsing all files...

Do you have any clues, ideas of "the best way" to implement this process?
Thank you!